# Why can't Intel do 5Ghz Ad-hoc where there are also dedicated 5Ghz routers?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router

I guess the title is kind of self explainatory.
I was looking around a solution as to why I can't use 5Ghz as the hotspot's band, so I can use higher speeds on VRidge (an app that streams SteamVR to your android phone, and I'm pretty sure it also works with oculus and openVR), so I need to be able to have a pretty fast network, which only 5Ghz can do.
Now, I had searched around for the solution a long time ago, but I dropped it and came back now. I found out that this happens due to "legal reasons", but I haven't actually read anything that proves it... I have read that on Intel's FAQ, but not the actual legal papers. The part that I find the most stupid is that it can't be due to possible interference with government stuff, because there are plenty of 5Ghz routers around where I live, which should be even more powerful than my laptop's adapter.
Can someone explain to me why that happens?
If it helps, my adapter is an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160...

Comment: Hotspot != ad-hoc. To host a 5 GHz network, you need radar detection and whatnot *except* on channels 36-48.

Comment: "Why" questions aren't really able to be answered here. How and What questions will have concrete information we can convey, but a why question is looking for information that is very much subject to opinion, or may be unknown. For instance, Intel has not published a document stating why they won't do this, so there is no way for us to know unless some high-level Intel exec cruises this forum, and then they likelihood that they'd answer your question is likely nil.

Answer (score 2):

In the 802.11/Wi-Fi world, "ad-hoc" is usually just the more accessible term for what the 802.11 standard calls IBSS mode. In an IBSS mode network, none of the participating devices acts as an AP (a.k.a. "hotspot", "wireless router"). There is no central device publishing/controlling the IBSS cell; all devices in the cell participate as equals.

In some countries, some 5GHz channels use frequencies that may be in use by nearby radar installations. These channels are called "radar channels" or "Dynamic Frequency Selection" (DFS) channels, because 802.11 equipment is only allowed to use these channels if some device in control of the network is constantly looking for radar-like radio energy signatures on the channel, and can quickly tell all clients to leave the channel if radar energy is detected.

Since IBSS networks don't have a central controller like an AP, they don't fit the criteria for using DFS channels. This issue has caused some implementors (vendors) to just not bother supporting IBSS in 5GHz at all. It turns out that most people never use IBSS in 2.4GHz either, so removing it from all products wouldn't be a huge loss for society.

The Wi-Fi Alliance recognizes that IBSS mode was a bit of a failure in the marketplace, and has tried to replace it. First they floated Wi-Fi Direct (Wi-Fi P2P), but it was also pretty much a failure, so now they're trying again with Wi-Fi Aware (Wi-Fi NAN, Neighbor-Aware Networking), which may also be a failure.

**tl;dr:** The architecture of ad-hoc (IBSS) mode doesn't easily comply with government-regulatory rules for use of most of the 5GHz band, so some vendors don't bother trying.